# CollectionView location changes when changing device orientation and back

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation, collectionview

I'm having issues with the constraints in CollectionView.

The view looks perfect at first, but when it is rotated to landscape and then rotated back to portrait, the location changes.

Here is how it looks at first and how it is supposed to look like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNqQ8.png

But after I rotate to landscape the device and rotate it back to portrait, this is how it looks.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8cpZ.png

How can I fix this without messing up the way it looks like when in landscape orientation?

(I don't have enough reputation to post images, hence why the images are in links)

Comment: Check if frame of CollectionView or its superView is changed.

Comment: @KudoCC How do I do that? Looking from the code, there is nothing that states it would change the location. Here are the constraints. http://i.imgur.com/fv0uHkj.png

Comment: `NSLog` the frame before and after rotation.

Comment: @KudoCC How exactly can I NSLog a frame?